# Multibinding XamDataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, infragistics

I am trying to use the following [code example from the Infragistics site](http://www.infragistics.com/samples/wpf/data-grid/SelectedDataItems) and I'd like edits in the XamDataCards to be reflected in the XamDataGrid.  However, my DataSource for the XamDataGrid is an `ObservableCollection<Companies>` in my ViewModel.  How can I also bind to the card and relay updates back to my `Companies` object in the ViewModel?

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid x:Name="dgCompanies" Theme="IGTheme" DataSource="{Binding Companies}" SelectedDataItemsScope="RecordsOnly">
  <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
    <igDP:FieldSettings CellClickAction="SelectCell" AllowEdit="True"/>
  </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
</igDP:XamDataGrid>
<igDP:XamDataCards x:Name="XamDataCards1"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       DataSource="{Binding Path=SelectedDataItems, ElementName=dgCompanies}"
                       Theme="IGTheme">
```

**Edit: Added ViewModel**

```
public class CompanyMgmtViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Object> _Companies = null;

    public ObservableCollection<Object> Companies
    {
        get { return _Companies; }
        set
        {
            if (_Companies != value)
            {
                _Companies = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(GetPropertyName(() => Companies));
            }
        }
    }
    public CompanyMgmtViewModel()
    {
        this.LoadData();
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Object> records = new ObservableCollection<Object>();

        var results = from res in AODB.Context.TCompanies
                      select res;
        foreach (var item in results)
            if (item != null) records.Add(item);
        Companies = records;
    }
}
```

The Model/Context code is just EF Database First generated.

Comment: Did you implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MVVMLight to RaisePropertyChanged.

Comment: Can you share your ViewModel code and model code.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged has to be implemented in your Model class.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, your input helped me arrive at an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't have gotten to this answer without Theodosius' and Ganesh's input - so thanks to them, they both had partial answers.

I first tried to bind the SelectedDataItems of the XamDataGrid to the XamDataCards by way of a property on the ViewModel as Theodosius suggested, but that wasn't enough.  Thanks to Ganesh, I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on my model objects, by inheriting from ObservableObject in MVVMLight (how did I not know the Model needed this?).

Below are the relevant pieces of code to make it work. 
I also implemented PropertyChanged.Fody [as documented here](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2014/06/using-fodypropertychanged-for-automatic.html); that's where the `TypedViewModelBase<T>` and removal of `RaisePropertyChanged()` comes from.
I'm also creating my Model objects by using a LINQ/Automapper `.Project().To<T>()` call [which can be found here](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code).

**Model**

```
 public class Company : ObservableObject
{
    public Company() { }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string strName { get; set; }
    public string strDomicileCode { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class CompanyMgmtViewModel : TypedViewModelBase<Company>
{
    private ObservableCollection<Object> _Companies = null;
    private Object[] _selectedCompany = null;

    public Object[] Company
    {
        get { return _selectedCompany; }
        set
        {
            if (_Company != value)
            {
                _selectedCompany = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Object> Companies
    {
        get { return _Companies; }
        set
        {
            if (_Companies != value)
            {
                _Companies = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public CompanyMgmtViewModel()
    {
        this.LoadData();
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Object> records = new ObservableCollection<Object>();

        var results = AODB.Context.TCompanies.Project().To<Company>();
        foreach (var item in results)
            if (item != null) records.Add(item);
        Companies = records;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid   x:Name="dgCompanies" 
                Theme="IGTheme"  
                DataSource="{Binding Companies, Mode=OneWay}" 
                SelectedDataItemsScope="RecordsOnly" 
                SelectedDataItems="{Binding Company}">
                  ...
<igDP:XamDataCards x:Name="XamDataCards1"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       DataSource="{Binding ElementName=dgCompanies, Path=SelectedDataItems}"
                       Theme="IGTheme">
```

Comment: MvvMLight has a ViewModelBase that you can use, it already has INotifyPropertyChanged in included, if you didn't know

Comment: Yeah, ViewModelBase inherits from ObservableObject.  And PropertyChanged.Fody is kind of amazing about cleaning up all of the repetitive `RaisePropertyChanged` verbiage. The TypedViewModelBase is a slick addition too.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to bind your XamDataGrid's SelectedDataItems property to a property of type object[] ie. SelectedCompanies in your ViewModel and bind to that for your XamDataCards' datasource.

The accepted answer in this thread has a sample that shows how to do this, albeit with a ListBox instead of XamDataCards:
http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/89122.aspx

Just replace that ListBox with your XamDataCards control, it works and updates the XamDataGrid.  The ViewModel in the example is contained in the MainWindow code-behind, so it is MVVM like you want.

more info:
http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2014.1/CLR4.0/html/xamDataGrid_Selected_Data_Items.html

IG's SelectedDataItems is an object[] :
http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2014.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v14.1~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataPresenterBase~SelectedDataItems.html

Comment: if you don't want the cards to be only the selected items (are you wanting to show every company in XamDataCards?), you would simply bind XamDataCards datasource to the same collection you bound XamDataGrid to)

Comment: Thanks Theodosius, your pointing me in the direction of `Object[]` helped me arrive at answer!